# How to enable ActiveRecord to support CJK query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

After `rails console`, I can execute the following query:

```
 1.9.3-p551 :001 > ActivityObject.where(:title => "kiketurpis integer aliquet")
```

And I got a unique answer existed in database. But if I enter:

```
1.9.3-p551 :002 >   ActivityObject.where(:title => '第一个纵纹')
```

(In double quotes there is a Chinese string.) I got all records in table `activity_objects`, which means I can not use Chinese string in predicate `where`.

Also, I can directly query this record using the Chinese string under `psql`:

```
vish_development=# select * from activity_objects where title = '第一个纵纹';
```

So my question is that what should I do for enabling `CJK string` in ActiveRecord's `where` or like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After [Frederick Cheung](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1064226/frederick-cheung) answer me in maillist 
[Ruby on Rails: Talk](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rubyonrails-talk/M4WD1M9x_sc), I finally found the answer.

Now it works fine!

Because ruby 1.9 does not use utf-8 as default encode:

```
 1.9.3-p551 :001 > __ENCODING__.name
 => "US-ASCII"
```

For UTF-8, I used the following commands:

```
 bash-3.2$ export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
 bash-3.2$ rails c
 Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.22)
  1.9.3-p551 :001 > __ENCODING__.name
  => "UTF-8"
```

After that, I get the right record when I run the previous query:

```
1.9.3-p551 :002 > ActivityObject.where(:title => '第一个纵纹')

 ActivityObject Load (29.5ms)  SELECT "activity_objects".* FROM "activity_objects" WHERE "activity_objects"."title" = '第一个纵纹'
=> [#<ActivityObject id: 648, created_at: "2015-06-21 14:41:19", updated_at: "2015-06-21 14:41:19", object_type: "Excursion", like_count: 0, title: "第一个纵纹", description: "整的行不？", follower_count: 1, visit_count: 5, language: "independent", age_min: 0, age_max: 0, notified_after_draft: false, comment_count: 0, popularity: 0, download_count: 0, qscore: 500000, reviewers_qscore: nil, users_qscore: nil, ranking: 0, title_length: 1, desc_length: 1, tags_length: 1, scope: 0, avatar_file_name: nil, avatar_content_type: nil, avatar_file_size: nil, avatar_updated_at: nil, teachers_qscore: nil>]
```