# What parameter should I use for non-english's charset_table in query "select ... where match('parameter')"?

Tags: sphinx, non-ascii-characters

For supporting Chinese or CJK, I used a including [CJK characters](https://gist.github.com/edouard/277986)' `charset_table` in `sphinx.conf`, 
after indexing and starting `searchd`, I used a client `mysql` to connect it:

```
mysql -h 0 -P 9306
```

and I can query and get all records using the following command:

```
mysql> select * from excursion_core;
```

But if I append `where match` I get nothing:

```
mysql> select * from excursion_core where match('kike');
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

For verifying whether such a new `charset_table` impact this, I used the old `sphinx.conf` only for english and run the same command:

```
mysql> select * from excursion_core where match('kike');
```

I can get all the records matching the string 'kike'.

I guess I should use a different string for CJK's charset, but I don't know what string I should use? Any advice will be welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According my another similar question: [How to enable ActiveRecord to support CJK query?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30970840/1054800), I found the answer for this. I got the following information after running `locale`:

```
LANG=
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_CTYPE="UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_NUMERIC="C"
LC_TIME="C"
LC_ALL=
```

The "C" is not for `UTF-8`, so I executed the command:

```
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

It changed the `locale`'s result:

```
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Then I can get the right records when I run the question's query in question:

```
mysql> select * from excursion_core where match('kike');
```